Horror movie where girl's dad is killed by people when young and she then kills their kids when she grows up?
I watched this when I was young. I think it is a horror movie, but not 100 percent sure. Basically, the girl witnessed her dad being set on fire by some people who lived in the area when she was young. When she grew up she had a party with those peoples kids at some house and they started dying one by one. At the end of the film it is revealed that this girl is behind all the killings to take revenge for her dad. She kills all of these peoples kids who burned her dad alive. I remember it was A HUGE shock when it was revealed she was behind everything. She had no accomplice or anything, it was just her all along.
It is a older movie, early 2000s or late nineties I would say. That's all I can remember. Thanks.
